# let var or var to let

Tags: javascript, scope, var, let

In the last couple of months, I've been learning a lot about JavaScript. Having abused the languages for years, I dare say that I now have a better understanding of the language and I've come to *love* the benefits of its functional nature.

Lately I've taken up learning Scheme, but that's just for fun. Browsing the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) I noticed that JS, though lacking block scope, does have a keyword that can be used to declare a variable local to a given block, much like Scheme's `let`:

```
for (var i=0;i<someArray.length;i++)
{
    console.log(someArray[i]);
}
console.log(i);//will log someArray's length
```

Whereas:

```
for (let i=0;i<someArray.length;i++)
{
    console.log(someArray[i]);
}
console.log(i);//undefined
```

So what I want to know now is: Why isn't `let` used more often? Has it got something to do with X-browser support? Is it just one of those *lesser-known-goodies*?
In short, what are the advantages of using `var` over `let`, what are the caveats?

As far as I can tell, the behaviour of `let` is, if anything, more consistent (double declarations in a single block raise a `TypeError`, except for function bodies (ECMA6 drafts fix this, though). 
To be honest, apart from this feature/keyword not being very well known, I struggle to think of *any* argument against using `let` for loops, or anywhere where a temporary variable makes for more readable code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, it has entirely to do with browser support. Currently only Firefox implements it *(since it's part of their superset of ECMAScript)*.

But it is [coming in ES6](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3alet), so there's hope...

I doubt it could be said that there are many benefits to `var` over `let` given that both are supported. I think the mantra is going to be *"`let` is the new `var`"*

Comment: Can't accept your answer (5 more minutes), but you're absolutely right, and I share your hopes... Silly, though, I'm currently using Chrome, and if I had just taken the time to open my console and try `let x = 1;` I'd have known there was a problem there. Silly, but still: `let`'s hope everybody who reads this question puts in a request to support let ASAP in the ECMA mailing list :)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Yeah, last I heard their target is December 2013, so we've got some waiting, but you can enable some of the new features that have been implemented in Chrome by setting a startup flag to allow experimental JavaScript. Not sure if `let` is included among those. To set those, type `chrome://flags/` in the address bar of chrome.

Comment: Just enabled experimental features, and `let` is supported, however there are some differences between FF and chrome, though part of it might be down to the way the console _eval_'s the code. Anyway a big +1 and thanks for the link

Comment: TypeScript will have `let` support in the 1.4 version: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/904

Comment: @Vadorequest: That's besides the point, given that TS is just transcompiled into JS. This question is about the various JS implementations, not transcompilers/X-compilers and how they deal with ES6 features.