# Do function arguments support a default value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

While looking at a question related to porting a [PHP function to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656887/whats-wrong-with-my-javascript-code/).  I saw what I assumed was incorrect JavaScript:

```
function my_isnum(str, negative=false, decimal=false)
```

Then I tried this in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M9KTN/1/):

```
function my_isnum(str, negative=false, decimal=-2)
{
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log(str);
    console.log(negative);
    console.log(decimal);
}
my_isnum("5", "Hi");
```

And to my utter amazement this is what I see in the Firebug console:

```
["5", "Hi"]
5
Hi
-2
```

Now in Chrome this is what I see:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

What I don't understand is this an example of some early standard being supported by Firefox (the MDN on [`function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) doesn't seem to mention this)?

Comment: I'm amazed FF shows that too!

Comment: Firefox's JavaScript is a superset of ECMAScript 3. It has features that are not standard syntax. Included among those are array comprehensions, `let` expressions, and destructuring assignment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This seems to be in the ECMAScript 6 specification and is at the moment only supported by Firefox

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters

Comment: Ahhh!  I knew it.  Thanks for the link :)

Comment: Darn, my O'Reilly Javascript: The Definitive Guide is out of date and I didn't know it.

Comment: You can turn it on in chrome, too, by enabling experimental features, just open a tab and type `chrome://flags/` in the address bar... The implementation may differ from mozilla's, just like the ECMA6 [new `var` aka `let`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568325/let-var-or-var-to-let)

Answer (score 8):

Lostsource's answer is correct, come ECMA6, default values are very likely to be supported, I think it will, but as it is still a working draft, you can't really be sure... For now, you can use the logical or:

```
function foo(bar, foobar)
{
    bar = bar || 'foobar';//once
    foobar = foobar || !!bar || true;//or multiple times
```

This works, sort of, like a ternary. The expressions are resolved, from left to right: as soon as JS encounters a truthy value, that's what will be assigned:

```
var someVar = false || undefined || null || 0 || 1;
```

Will assign 1 to `someVar`. If no values are passed to a function, all arguments are assigned `undefined` by default, so in that case:

```
myArgument = myArgument || 'default';
//is the same as:
myArgument = undefined || 'default';//evaluates to "default"
```

But when you pass `false` as an argument, or `null`, or an empty string, the default value will be assigned, so be careful.
In those cases an if/ternary is a better fit (as seen in theJollySin's answer). The ternary equivalent of which is:

```
some_val = typeof some_val === 'undefined' ? 'default' : some_val;
```

Answer (score 4):

Sort of. You can do something like:

```
function the_func(some_val) {
    // if some_val is not passed to the_func 
    if (typeof some_val == 'undefined') {
        some_val = 'default_some_val';
    }

    // now you can use some_val in the remaining parts of the method
}
```

Comment: maybe with two fewer lines though.

Comment: And this is how 100% of my code and every other argument checking code I have ever seen in JavaScript looks.

Comment: Can do something like: some_val = (typeof some_val !== 'undefined') ?  some_val : 'defaultVal';

Comment: @javaBean007 Correct, there are shorter ways to do this.  But it is a beginner question, so I opted for the most descriptive solution that is the easiest to read.