# object literal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have been using JavaScript for years, but I just found out that this does not cause a syntax error:

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/V5wNu/

```
{
    var a = "Hello";
    alert("Hello world");
}
console.log(a);   //"Hello world"
```

Although there is no block scope, it still works like if `{}` are not there.

I thought `{}` is an Object literal, and all it accepts inside are:

```
{
    key: content
    get function(){ ... }
    set function(){ ... }
}
```

But the JavaScript interpreter seems to know they are scripts and it just execute it like normal.

I know that there's some keywords in JS that the interpreter will ignore, such as

```
javascript:
```

And if you add it to lines in your code:

```
var a = "Hello";
javascript: console.log(a);   //this will work
```

It still works.

But then according to that logic, if `{a: "b"}` is valid, why isn't `a: "b"` valid?

Comment: Even though there is only function scope, that doesn't mean there are no blocks. They only do not create a scope of their own.

Comment: JS doesn't have block-scope _Yet_. It's very likely -if not sure- to be part of ECMAScript 1.6 (Harmony): [it introduces the `let` keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568325/let-var-or-var-to-let)

Comment: Even if this works it doesn't mean it's valid. Will throw error on every validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a: "b"
```

**is** valid.

When in a [block](http://es5.github.io/#x12.1) and not an [object initializer](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5), it's simply a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) (that could have been used in a `break` statement) followed by a useless string literal.

Note : As there are already 3 false answers here, I'll precise that `{...}` makes a block apart if the preceding code makes it so that an expression is needed (see http://www.2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Okay, this was too quick.

Object litterals are a pair of curly braces containing a (possibly empty) list of `field` `:` `value` (which can be an object litteral itself) pairs separated by `,`s.

However, a (gramatically) valid code block can also be written with the same syntax:

```
function a () { l: x }}
```

here `l` is considered a label and `x` a statement consisting on a variable reference.

The difference in usage will be purely contextual (hence my only partial first answer).

If you call a function or initialize a variable, the same construct will be interpreted as a litteral object

```
a ( { l:x } )
a = { l:x }
```

Comment: But... That's just false ! You can have an object literal not preceded by an = sign.

Comment: Try `console.log({})` for example.

Comment: @dystroy You're right, this was an oversimplification. I meant the interpretation was contextual. See my edit.